# Function with input type double in classdef

Tags: matlab, oop

I am starting with oop in Matlab and seem to miss something.

```
classdef car < handle

properties (Access = public)
    a
    b
end

methods
    function obj = update(obj)
        obj.b = updateB(obj.a, obj.b);
    end

    function B = updateB(a, b)
        B = a + b;
    end
end

end
```

I get the famous `Undefined function 'updateB' for input arguments of type 'double'.` error every time, I try to call the function `update`. Oddly, it works if I change `updateB` to:

```
function B = updateB(obj)
    B = obj.a + obj.b;
end
```

What am I missing? I do not always want to call `updateB` with obj, because I want to use the function without using the actual object's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, if you don't want the method to rely on a specific instance, use this approach:

```
methods
    function obj = update(obj)
        obj.b = car.updateB(obj.a, obj.b);
    end
end

methods (Static)
    function B = updateB(a, b)
        B = a + b;
    end
end
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Can you explain me, why I suddendly have to call the function in the style 'class.function()'? Is it best practice to always call internal functions like that?

Comment: Static methods don't belong to a specific instance. They are, as the name says, static routines defined within your class. So you have to call them as ClassName.Function. For detailed infos: https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html